# On Marx's theory of human nature

Tags: marx, marxism

Does anyone have resources on Marx's theory of human nature (or 'species-essence' as he refers to it). I understand that he refers to human nature as the totality of social relations. But where does the labor part factor into it here, and is 'homo faber' an accurate term to describe it.

Comment: I'm not sure Marx ever spelled out anything specific. He generally followed Locke, I think, but by Marx's time 'State of Nature' arguments were passé, and Marx was more interested in social relationships. The individual essentialism of the earlier era wouldn't have seemed important to him.

Comment: @Ericleast992 I have no idea what Marx thought or said but the statement "*human nature as the totality of social relations*" strikes me as the equivalent of claiming that the nature of the CO₂ molecule is the totality of its chemical relations, which is clearly false.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: I don't see why you assert that statement as 'clearly false'. Most everything important or useful about a given molecule has to do with its interactions with surrounding atoms, molecules, particles/waves, energy fields, or systems, We care about CO<sub>2</sub> because our bodies expel it, it reflects thermal radiation, it's part of the life cycle of plants, it's the end-product of certain kinds of combustion, it has a useful melting point, etc. A molecule of CO<sub>2</sub> in isolation is at best of pedantic, academic concern.

Comment: @TedWrigley The nature of the CO₂ molecule goes beyond its chemical relations, at least this is what comes out of particle physics and quantum mechanics. 2. "*Most everything important or useful about a given molecule (...)*" Nature is what it is, not just what is important to us. What is important to us is only one part of its nature, maybe what you could call its macroscopic properties. 3. "*A molecule of CO₂ in isolation*" I didn't talk about the molecule of CO₂ in isolation.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: I can't speak to metaphysical claims about things that exist beyond what we can observe. What I'm saying is that we only *know* about the properties of CO<sub>2</sub> because of its interactions with other particles, molecules, and fields, and most of those properties are *interaction* property. Reactivity, solubility, mass, boiling point, color, etc...: what are these except the properties of CO<sub>2</sub> when it *interacts* with the world around it?

Comment: @Speakpigeon: But this is beside the point in any case. The difference between a beaker of CO<sub>2</sub> and a human society is that the individual members of the first have identical and invariant properties while the individual members of the second have properties that differ between members and vary across time. Even if I were to grant your claim for CO<sub>2</sub> (which I don't) the analogy to human society is specious.

Comment: @TedWrigley "*individual members of the second have properties that differ between members and vary across time*" Only because you arbitrarily focus on more superficial properties and ignore their fundamental properties. Just like CO₂ molecules, human beings are natural beings and as such they have the same fundamental properties. CO₂  also have different superficial properties. One is here, the other is there. One is going fast, the other is moving more slowly. And their constituants most likely won't have the same configuration relative to each other, really much like human beings do.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: again, you're invoking metaphysics. Unless you can define and experimentally demonstrate these ostensible 'fundamental properties' you're merely talking through your hat. I'm not suggesting these properties don't exist, mind you. I"m suggesting that you don't know what they are (any more than anyone else does), and that your invocation of them is a matter of personal faith, not a matter of science or philosophy.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: I'm fine with faith, but I'm not fine with those who conflate faith and fact.

Comment: @TedWrigley "*you don't know what they are*" Of course I know what they are and I don't need to. All I need is that my readers also believe that they exist. This is how the logic of verbal communication works. The crucial point, though, is that I explained my view and now you can think about it. 2. "*faith and fact*" You may have faith that you know me enough to make that quip but the fact is you don't.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: Ah, the Big Lie, wunnerful... So, since you claim to know the fundamental principles of human nature, feel free to share them. We readers will either learn something profound or have a good laugh. And if you choose not to share, well... I'll take that as proof that you're just lying to save face, and be satisfied *reductio ad absurdum* style. Works for me any way you cut it.

Comment: @TedWrigley "*since you claim to know the fundamental principles of human nature*" Whoa. You seem to like hyperbole very much. Your problem now is that I never claimed to know *the fundamental principles of human nature*.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: And I quote, from your last post: *"Of course I know what they are..."* That doesn't seem particularly open to interpretation.

Comment: @TedWrigley Ah, crap, this is *of crouse* not what I meant to write. I meant that of course I **don't** know. Couldn't you have guessed by yourself? The whole sentence was "Of course I know what they are **and I don't need to**", which doesn't make sense until you replace "*I know*" by "I don't know".

Comment: @Speakpigeon: The passage worked as written, so I didn't see a need to question it.  But my apologies for misunderstanding. But in that case you're right back to expressing a tenet of faith, one that you and (some of) your readers share. Faith is fine, but it's not fact, and shouldn't be treated as such. I happen not to share that belief, however, so you can't really expect me to agree with you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137895/discussion-between-speakpigeon-and-ted-wrigley).